# Progression from indefinite integral to definite integral - $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{5-3\cos x} dx$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{5-3\cos x} dx$$

We can evaluate indefinite one first - $\int\frac{1}{5-3\cos x}dx = \frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(2\tan(\frac{x}{2})) + C$. The problem is that $\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(2\tan(\frac{2\pi}{2}))-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(2\tan(\frac{0}{2}))=0$ but there's a hint on this excercise that the value of this definite integral is greater than $0$. So, what went wrong? What's the trap I've fallen into during evaluation of this integral?

Comment: the problem is that the primitive function has discontinuities :v

Comment: this discrepancy amounts to a "branch cut" problem

Comment: Indeed, qiubit has fallen through the branch cut :) .

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}=\int_{0}^{\pi}+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}$$

You should do so because the primitive function is discontinues at $x=\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

the graph of $\cos x$ is symmetric about $x = \pi,$  therefore $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{5-3\cos x} = 2 \int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{5-3\cos x}  = \tan^{-1}\left(2\tan(x/2)\right)\Big|_0^{\pi} =\frac{\pi}2.$$

Comment: Question about notation - is $\tan^{-1}\left(2\tan(x/2)\right)\Big|_0^{\pi} = \tan^{-1}\left(2\tan(\pi/2)\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(2\tan(0/2)\right)$? But $\tan(\pi/2)$ is undefined. Why is it $\pi/2$ then?

Comment: @qiubit, use $\pi-$ and $tan(\pi/2 -) = \infty$